# How to enforce char(N) datatype instead of varchar(N) in django model field

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

As per django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/

it's ORM create `varchar` field instead of `char`.

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and equivalent sql statement

```
CREATE TABLE myapp_person (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL
);
```

so here we can see it is using varchar, but can I use `char` instead. I'm unable to find a way.
apart from manually altering the column

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want this?

Comment: wouldn't that improve the db performence if few `varchar` becomes `char`? I'm just curious, I may be wrong @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams this type of thing is very useful for maintaining data integrity. e.g. I have a field that can either be a 5 character code or null. That's it. Anything else should fail. In OPs case I'm not sure it's optimal (it will require 30 characters for each name and a lot of padding with spaces - eww) but it has it's use case.

Answer (score 8):

For those who struggle with the anwser given by @andrai-avram,
this is what that would look like:

```py
from django.db import models
class ActualCharField(models.CharField):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        varchar: str = super().db_type(connection)
        char: str = varchar.replace('varchar', 'char')
        return char
```

And then just use this class instead of the default `django.db.models.CharField`

Answer (score 6):

I think your best bet is to write a [custom field type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-model-fields/), base it on `CharField` and alter its `db_type()` method. Check relevant example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-model-fields/#custom-database-types)

Comment: Please see my answer below for an example (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61561841/3017716)